# Method from another class error

Tags: java, class, methods, linked-list, lookup

I am trying to create a lookup table with a linked list instead of an array. When declaring the maximum size of the table I get an error. This is the code for the size of the linked list in the class "SequenceList":

```
public int size() {
    Node nodePointer = listHead;
    int size = 0;
    while (nodePointer != null) {
        size += 1;
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

and this is the code at the lookup table class called "Linear":

```
public Linear(int size) {        
    seq = new SequenceList(size);
}
```

The error is that "SequenceList to SequenceList() cannot be applied to (int)"
Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `When declaring the maximum size of the table I get an error` Which error? Please, post the stacktrace or any relevant message this error gives you

Comment: And is SequenceList a class you wrote? Or a class from an existing library?

Comment: It's a class I wrote. I edited the question to include the error as well

Comment: Are you sure you have a constructor in your SequenceList class which takes an `int size` parameter? Please post all the necessary code.